# Change array of name from Last, First to First Last

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reformat an array of names from ['last, first'] to ['first last']. I have worked out how to do it on a single name, but am having trouble reformatting the entire array of names.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 <body>

<script>

class1 = ['Schmo, Joe', 'Smith, Billy','Brown, John']

function reverseName () {
for (a = 0; a < class1.length; a++) {
   classA = class1[a].split(',').reverse.join(' ');
}
}
document.getElementById("firstLast").innerHTML = classA;


</script>

<p id = "firstLast"></p>
</body>
```

"ClassA" will be the output array with the names in the format "Joe Schmo", "Billy Smith" etc. 
Thanks!

Comment: UM, you never call your function and you are referencing classA before you run it. AND you keep overriding the variable classA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it done. You need to declare `classA` as an empty array, and then assign each name from `class1` to the same index in `classA`.

```
function reverseName () {
    var classA = [];
    for (a = 0; a < class1.length; a++) {
         classA[a] = class1[a].split(',').reverse.join(' ');
    }

    return classA;
}
```

Comment: Faster than a speeding bullet -- thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` (ECMAScript 5):

```
var classA = ['Schmo, Joe', 'Smith, Billy','Brown, John'].map(function(item) {
    return item.split(', ').reverse().join(' ');
});
```

Or, with loops,

```
var class1 = ['Schmo, Joe', 'Smith, Billy','Brown, John'],
    l = class1.length,
    classA = Array(l);
for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
   classA[i] = class1[i].split(', ').reverse().join(' ');
}
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor Please don't include `document.write` in my answers.

Comment: For the purposes of illustrating a working example in a code snippet I don't see the problem with using it. Obviously I wouldn't recommend people use document.write in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign it back looks like a typo

```
class1[a] = class1[a].split(',').reverse.join(' ');
```

You can also use the map function of array as @Oriol points out -- which is probably better.  But the above line is the "fix" to your code.